# Square OkHttp Websocket connection failing few seconds after getting connected

Tags: java, android, kotlin, websocket, boringssl

Websocket connection is getting failed in a few android device(eg Xiaomi POCO X2) with the below error, it is happening few seconds after handshake is succeded.

After WS connected it is getting disconnected with the below error

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Read error: ssl=0xb400006f72a510c8: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:1e000065:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT (third_party/openssl/boringssl/src/crypto/fipsmodule/cipher/e_aes.c:1065 0x7009c44bee:0x00000000)
error:1000008b:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC (third_party/openssl/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:294 0x7009c44bee:0x00000000)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(:com.google.android.gms@240812031@24.08.12 (150400-608507424):-2)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.read(:com.google.android.gms@240812031@24.08.12 (150400-608507424):34)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket$SSLInputStream.read(:com.google.android.gms@240812031@24.08.12 (150400-608507424):11)
    at okhttp3.internal.ws.MessageDeflaterKt.read(MessageDeflaterKt.java:102)
    at okhttp3.internal.ws.MessageDeflaterKt.read(MessageDeflaterKt.java:23)
    at aq.z.r(z.java:31)
    at aq.z.X(z.java:0)
    at aq.z.readByte(z.java:3)
    at zp.j.c(j.java:22)
    at zp.g.f(g.java:252)
    at io.ktor.client.engine.HttpClientEngine$executeWithinCallContext$1.onResponse(HttpClientEngine.java:455)
    at rp.g.run(g.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
```

okHttpVersion - okhttp:4.9.3

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.